# Eclipse kepler doesn't create J2EE application

Tags: apache, tomcat

I cant get an option of creating for .jsp file in eclipse 4.3. I already installed the plugins too. I can create as static web project but in that i cant create .jsp file, i can create only html file using html template.
Could you please help us. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have eclipse java ee or switch in your eclipse perspective to JavaEE 
Only if you are in proper perspective you have access to create right javaEE projects and other files

this link should help you a lot (it's about how to get know perspective)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_perspectives.htm

and this one describes so well this whole process

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av6zh817QEc

as you can see in right corner of window this developer have javaEE perspective and he can:

1. Dynamic Web Project
2. jsp file - choose (file, new, other and you will be in new wizard window and you need to choose Web folder and there will be your jsp file)
3. servlet - it's nothing more then java class extends HttpServlet for example
   -> public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet{}

I hope this can help you.